# Make string title case using ucfirst

Tags: php, title-case, ucfirst

**I'm probably missing something really obvious.**

While converting a bunch of string before inserting them in a array I noticed some string where different among each other because of first char being uppercase or not. I decided then to use `ucfirst` to make first character uppercase but it seems it doesn't work properly, I have had a look around on the web trying to figure out why this is happening but I had no luck.

```
$produtto = 'APPLE';
echo ucfirst($produtto);
//output: APPLE
```

If I use instead `mb_convert_case`

```
$produtto = 'APPLE';
echo mb_convert_case($produtto, MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8");
//Output: Apple
```

Comment: You first must convert to lowercase `strtolower()`, then use `ucfirst()` after. Your string is already in uppercase, so it won't work the way you are using it now. I was faced with that too at one point, so I learned it the hard way. lol it happens ;-)

Comment: Remember this, as someone once told me many many moons ago: "Computers are actually stupid, you have to tell them what to do".

Comment: eheheh @fred you are right!

Comment: Hehehe, *circa 1985* actually. cheers ;-)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`ucfirst()` only looks at the first character so you should convert to lowercase first.

Use this:

```
$produtto = 'APPLE';
echo ucfirst(strtolower($produtto));
//output: Apple
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first case I assume you would first need to turn them lowercase with `strtolower`, and then use `ucfirst` on the string.

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-case.php

MB_CASE_TITLE is not the same as ucfirst(). ucfirst is only interested in the first character. MB_CASE_TITLE is about the whole string and making it an initial capital string.

Answer (score 0):

read the manual! APPLE = uppercase.. so ucfirst does nothing.

www.php.net/ucfirst

```
$foo = 'hello world!';
$foo = ucfirst($foo);             // Hello world!

$bar = 'HELLO WORLD!';
$bar = ucfirst($bar);             // HELLO WORLD!
$bar = ucfirst(strtolower($bar)); // Hello world!
```